# How to add another object to state object in loop ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, concatenation, state

I can not figure out how to add new object data to `boxes` when looping through data. My code is:

```
const initialState = {
      input: '',
      imageUrl: '',
      box: {},
      boxes: {},      
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false,
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password:'',
        entries: 0,
        joined: '' 
      }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState
  };  

  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {       
    const facesDataArray = data.outputs[0].data.regions;
    console.log(facesDataArray);
    let i;
    for (i=0;i<facesDataArray.length;i++) {
      const clarifaiFace = facesDataArray[i].region_info.bounding_box;
      const image = document.getElementById('inputImage');
      const width = Number(image.width);
      const height = Number(image.height);      
      this.setState ({
        box: {
         leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
         topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
         rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
         bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height) 
        }             
      })
        console.log('box value',this.state.box); 
        this.setState({boxes: this.state.boxes.concat(this.state.box)});         
    }         
  }
```

I get `box` object valuein console everytime it loops throught the data, but instead of adding this new data to `boxes` it ends up with `TypeError: this.state.boxes.concat is not a function`

I dont know how to solve this adding to `boxes` situation. Can anyone help??

Comment: ```boxes``` is an object, not an array. Hence, it does not have concat function. You can either change it to be an array, or modify the setState to ```this.setState({...this.state, boxes: {...this.state.boxes, this.state.box}});```

Comment: Damn, I knew it will be such an minor detail that I was missing. Changed it to array and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setState, value of this.state.box is not update right away.
so you have to use callback for setState.

```js
this.setState ({
        box: {
         leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
         topRow: clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
         rightCol: width - (clarifaiFace.right_col * width),
         bottomRow: height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row * height) 
        }             
}, ()=>{
   this.setState({boxes: [...this.state.boxes, this.state.box]); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For useState React Hook:

```js
const [assets, setAssets] = React.useState([]);

for (let i = 0; i <= currentNumberOfAssets; i++)
  if (await testCapitalTreasury.getTreasuryAssetIsIncludedById(i)) {
    setAssets((assets) => [
      ...assets,
      {
        assetSymbol: assetSymbol,
        chainName: chainName,
        quantity: quantity,
        priceInEth: priceInEth,
        priceInUSDC: priceInUSDC,
        valueInEth: valueInEth,
        valueInUSDC: valueInUSDC,
      },
    ]);
  }
```